# How to get provider using rainbowkit wallet if connected via walletconnect or coinbase

Tags: wallets, web3-providers, wagmi, rainbowkit

I'm using **rainbowkit** wallet which offers various wallet options such as **walletconnect** and **coinbase**.

My question is, if I'm connected via **metamask** then my web3 instance can use `window.ethereum` as provider.

But if I'm connected to other wallets like walletconnect or coinbase, can I still go with `window.ethereum` as provider?

i.e. `let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);`

if not, for other wallets where can I get its provider? is there an option to grab currently connected provider using **wagmi**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had to use signer object to get provider.

```
import { useSigner } from 'wagmi';

const {data: signer} = useSigner();

const web3 = new Web3((signer?.provider as any).provider);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `useProvider()` hook as detailed [in the docs](https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useProvider)

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like provider cannot be just passed as an argument.
`const provider = useProvider()`
`const web3 = new Web3(provider); <-- error`

Comment: Wagmi uses Ethers under the hood, so provider you get via the `useProvider()` hook is already an Ethers provider. All the hooks provided by Wagmi are there so you don't have to manually instantiate a provider. If you want to send a transaction, you can use the [useSendTransaction](https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useSendTransaction) hook. If you want to execute read functions from a contract, use the [useContractReads hook](https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useContractReads). And to use write contract functions, you can use the [useContractWrite hook](https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useContractWrite)

Comment: thanks, this is all because i'm using biconomy where transactions are sent to their [api](https://docs.biconomy.io/products/enable-gasless-transactions/choose-an-approach-to-enable-gasless/custom-implementation/2.-code-changes/api) As you can see in the example, it requires web3 instance with provider being passed

Answer (score 0):

In this example below, I'm using the wallet provider (browser wallet, walletconnect, etc) to get data from a smart contract.

```
import { useContractRead, useWalletClient } from "wagmi";

const { data: walletClient } = useWalletClient();
  const contractRead = useContractRead({
    address: contractAddress,
    abi: contractABI,
    functionName: "getAllProjects",
    walletClient: walletClient,
  });
```